# Computing the Density of Points on a 2D Plane

Tags: statistics

I have a chart with points scattered across it; many of which are tightly clustered. I wish to filter out all points that are not within these dense clusters of points. I have an idea of how to achieve this: to create a 2D histogram with bins of a specified size, and compute the density within each one, but I was wondering whether there exists a better means of doing so, and perhaps one without requiring the optimal bin size to be guessed.

May anyone suggest a means of achieving the above?

Comment: I don't have a good answer, but this sounds a lot like "despeckling" an image. Maybe if you look into the algorithms used for that, you can find something that works for your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have some criteria for what makes a cluster 'dense', what you mean by 'not within', and what percentage of all points you want to 'filter out'.

Maybe start with a univariate sample distribution and see if you can make sense of your task in this easier problem.

For example, a boxplot can show 'outliers' at the far left or right, that you might want to remove. But if you remove them, and do another boxplot, you are likely to see a new crop of outliers. There may or
may not be a 'reasonable' stopping point.

Also, if the data are bimodal, you might want to remove some points between the two clusters. What constitutes an isolated point between clusters? Can you explain the clusters according to some categorical variable, and then treat the clusters separately?

There are various traditional methods for multivariate data. One is *discriminant analysis,* in which you try to associate what might be clusters according to a categorical variable. You might want to try getting rid of points that are 'misclassified'. Also *cluster
analysis* can give some guidance how to define clusters, and you might want to get rid of points that are only 'borderline' in the clustering criteria.

You might get additional suggestions by posting this on 'crossvalidated'. However, a whole catalog of methods probably won't
do much good unless you can understand more clearly than you
state in your question, what you hope to accomplish by filtering
out points and how you decide when a particular datapoint is
irrelevant or harmful to your your analytic goals.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The points in question are eye tracked positions on a screen. I need to determine where the user focused his/her eyes. Cluster density in this case, I suppose, would mean that many of those points are within close proximity of each other. If one were to imagine a Gaussian curve then perhaps those within 1SD of the cluster centers.